# Cursor Vanishing When Moved to Right Side of Screen

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, cursor

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 with a RTX3070 and two monitors.

When the left monitor is flipped and I move the cursor to the right hand side of the right monitor, the cursor vanishes!

Using the keyboard I can change the monitor settings to mirror and then join display again (but both monitors in landscape) and then the cursor reappears.

If I leave the settings with both monitors in landscape everything works fine, but the way I have my desk/room setup it has to be flipped.

I have read things about coolbits but it's already disabled.

Already tried purging and reinstalling Nvidia drivers, tried both 460 and 470 versions. Same thing happens.

Anyone have a clue of what could be happening or how I could get more information to debug it better?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was because I had 2 GPUs, and I had messed around with the Xorg display settings.

What I had to do to fix this was restore the defaults, and get rid of a 2nd "Monitor" and "Screen", e.g. using VIM editing this file:

```
sudo vi /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

From there, I just made sure that my Screen0 and Monitor0 pointed to the GPU that was properly set up (i.e. not to my RTX 3090, which I think may be buggy, I don't know).  So my file has the following redirected and commented out parts like follows:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
#    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection
...


Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

#Section "Monitor"
#    Identifier     "Monitor1"
#    VendorName     "Unknown"
#    ModelName      "Unknown"
#    Option         "DPMS"
#EndSection
...

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Coolbits" "28"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

#Section "Screen"
#    Identifier     "Screen1"
#    Device         "Device1"
#    Monitor        "Monitor1"
#    DefaultDepth    24
#    Option         "Coolbits" "28"
#    SubSection     "Display"
#        Depth       24
#    EndSubSection
#EndSection
```